# Android Studio Java. Display a pop-up window in the background

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I display a popup when an app is in the background?
For example, I took the GetContact application, when a call is received from the user, a window with information about the call pops up on the screen.
How can this be done?
It is desirable with code examples, I will be very grateful.
Thank.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9tto.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add required permissions in your app manifest file:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  ```
- **Incoming call reciever**

  ```
  public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     try {
       System.out.println("Receiver start");
       String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
       String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

       if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State Number is -" + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
  ```
- **Ask Runtime permission in your MainActivity.**
- Add overlay view to display notification in screen.

  ```
  WindowManager wm =(WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test, null) 
  wm.addView(view, mParams)
  ```

Comment: The problem is that I don't need toast notifications, but a full-screen "activity" like an interstitial ad. How can this be done? thank

Comment: You can trigger a overlay view in the device with your XML design instead of Toast notification.

WindowManager  wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test, null)
wm.addView(view, mParams)

Comment: I'm new to Android Studio, only worked with Unity before. I would be very grateful if you can suggest examples of this implementation (any tutorials, videos, documentation). I urgently need to submit a project that will open a full-screen page in the background of the application. The page should look like interstitial ads.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is Drawing over other apps. It's a tricky feature of android that I personally love. You have to deal with WindowManager and you need SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission

Implementations are huge and I guess it's better to give you some links.

Here's a good explanation about floating widgets
https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064

This is kinda close to what you want: https://github.com/codebyshubham/Calling_Person_History

Also remember that custom roms like Xiaomi have some restrictions on these widgets.
Also a great open source floating app is called QuickLyric take a look at it it might help you a lot